# Which table design is better below?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 different design of table inside my Database which is have same purpose, and this is the first design

```
Table Name   : User                 Table Name   : Topic
Table Column : - idUser             Table Column : - idTopic
               - username                          - topicName
               - email                             - topicDescription

Table Name   : UserFollowing
Table Column : - id_user
               - relatedTable
               - relatedId
```

so, I have a project about user can follow topic and user can follow another user, in the first design case, I created table named UserFollowing to connect which row user follow (relatedID) and which type following (User or Topic) user follow useing relatedTable.

and here is my second design

```
Table Name   : User                 Table Name   : Topic
Table Column : - idUser             Table Column : - idTopic
               - username                          - topicName
               - email                             - topicDescription

Table Name   : UserFollowUser       Table Name   : UserFollowTopic
Table Column : - id_user            Table Column : - id_user
               - id_user_following                 - id_topic_following
```

which one is better to implement? the first one or the second one?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about constraints you should definitly use the second one.

Even if you are not using innodb and try to build your own constrains by application layer it is very useful to assign one foreign column to only one parent column. It is much more clean.